# How to pass two or more objects from views for render it in template

Tags: django

Im working on Django, i need pass two or more objects to a view, for render it in the template. I mean, 
i have one object, and this object can has two or more objects from other model, in the view i have:

```
def infoUsuario(request,id_usuario):
    user = info_productor_cultivador.objects.get(id=id_usuario)
    familiar = grupo_familiar.objects.filter(familiar_de_id=user)
    ctx = {'usuario':user,'familiar':familiar}
    return render_to_response('usuarios.html',ctx,context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

in the template:

```
{% for familiares in familiar %}
    <p>{{familiar.primer_nombre}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

The models:

```
class grupo_familiar(models.Model):
    familiar_de = models.ForeignKey(info_productor_cultivador)
    primer_nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class info_productor_cultivador(models.Model):
    primer_nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

First, instead "filter" in familiar object i has "get" but said me: "get() returned more than one grupo_familiar -- it returned 2!" looking for a solution i found it that i have to pass the "filter" query, this time i dont have errors from Django, but the "familiar" object does not render it in the template.

In other words, i think that i need is how to pass a foreign key in the view and render it in the template.

Thanks

Comment: Add your models pls. And you should read PEP8 for more standard coding style.

Comment: Edit your question and put the models there.

Comment: Ok, done. And thanks about PEP8 recommendations

Answer (score 1):

views

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def info_usuario(request, id_usuario):
    user = info_productor_cultivador.objects.get(id=id_usuario)
    familiar = grupo_familiar.objects.filter(familiar_de_id=user)
    ctx = { 'usuario': user, 'familiar': familiar }
    return render(request, 'usuarios.html', ctx }
```

template

```
{% for familiares in familiar %}
    <p>{{ familiar.primer_nombre }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```